# Convert Swift method using extend and append functions to Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift

I have this Swift method that I want to convert to Objective-C. The method is using the extend method of Array and as far as I understand it just adds an object to the array while calling itself again.

Swift:

```
///the method to serialized all the objects
    func serializeObject(object: AnyObject,key: String?) -> Array<HTTPPair> {
        var collect = Array<HTTPPair>()
        if let array = object as? Array<AnyObject> {
            for nestedValue : AnyObject in array {
                collect.extend(self.serializeObject(nestedValue,key: "\(key!)[]"))
            }
        } else if let dict = object as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
            for (nestedKey, nestedObject: AnyObject) in dict {
                var newKey = key != nil ? "\(key!)[\(nestedKey)]" : nestedKey
                collect.extend(self.serializeObject(nestedObject,key: newKey))
            }
        } else {
            collect.append(HTTPPair(value: object, key: key))
        }
        return collect
    }
```

What I've done so far in Objective-C.

```
- (NSArray*) serializeObject:(id)obj key:(NSString*)key
    {
    NSMutableArray* collect = [NSMutableArray array];
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
        NSArray* objArray = obj;
        if (obj)
            {
            for (id nestedObj in objArray)
                {
                [collect addObject:[self serializeObject:nestedObj key:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[]", key]]];
                }
            }
        }
    else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
        NSDictionary* dict = obj;
        if (dict)
            {
            for (NSString* nestedKey in dict)
                {
                NSString* newKey = key != nil ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[%@]", key, nestedKey] : nestedKey;
                id nestedObject = [dict objectForKey:newKey];
                if (nestedObject)
                    {
                    [collect addObject:[self serializeObject:nestedObject key:newKey]];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    else
        {
        [collect addObject:[[WEEHTTPPair alloc] initWithValue:obj andKey:key]];
        }
    return collect;
    }
```

The goal is to get an NSArray of WEEHTTPPair objects for every key/value pair in the dictionary but I lose the meaning of extend and append to apply in my Objective-C code. For me it looks like both are adding the object to the array which is created new anyway but it's more that I lack in knowledge so far.

[EDIT]

The method is used accordingly.

Swift.

```
///convert the parameter dict to its HTTP string representation
    func stringFromParameters(parameters: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) -> String {
        return join("&", map(serializeObject(parameters, key: nil), {(pair) in
            return pair.stringValue()
            }))
    }
```

I converted to Objective-C borrowed [BlockKits](https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit/tree/master/BlocksKit) map extension.

Objective-C.

```
- (NSString*) stringFromParameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters
    {
    WEENSArrayBlocksKit* blockKit = [WEENSArrayBlocksKit new];
    NSArray* serializedParams = [self serializeObject:parameters key:nil];
    NSArray* arrayParams = [blockKit bk_map:serializedParams withBlock:^id(id obj)
        {
        // obj is an array without the desired results
        WEEHTTPPair* httpPair = obj;
        NSString* stringValue = nil;
        if (httpPair)
            {
            stringValue = [httpPair stringValue];
            }
        return stringValue;
        }];
    NSString* joinedString = [arrayParams componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
    return joinedString;
    }
```

Comment: To me it looks pretty much straight forward. What did you think is missing?

Comment: I edited the question with more information of the issue. I am waiting an NSArray of WEEHTTPPair instead I get an NSArray that contains NSArray?! Still trying to debug why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
[collect addObject:[self serializeObject:nestedObject key:newKey]];
```

You are adding an `NSArray` to your `collect` object. Instead, you want to add the *objects contained within* the response to `collect`:

```
[collect addObjectsFromArray:[self serializeObject:nestedObject key:newKey]];
```

Comment: Yes, this was the missing part, extend is the addObjectsFromArray selector and I couldn't figure it out. Thanks.